# way to extract details like name , ph no from resume(ms word)

Tags: .net

i am trying to extract details such as name , address , qualification etc from resume(ms
word).....

i know resume are usually in different formats.....

so any ideas can be helpful.....

thank you

Comment: This question is way too broad. What is  your exact problem? Reading the MS Word file? Parsing the text to match different formats? I don't think anyone will help you this way.

Answer (score 0):

Its more easier to do this with excel. So ask for resumes in excel format if possible otherwise:

You need to create a `Word` object (there's a template for this in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010) and read the document text and analyze it. This method is very error-prone since different users may use different syntaxes. So again you need to force them adopt a unique syntax and we are back to the same position (Excel format).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the open source Apache Tika toolkit which can extract text from all of the Microsoft products suite and much more.

Here is a list of what it can parse: http://tika.apache.org/0.5/formats.html